# Deciding the pointing bucket of extendable hashing

Tags: database, hash, extending

I have an extendable hashing. need to insert values 23,31,5, 7,11,17, 2,3 . The hash function is h(x)=x mod 4. and the bucket size is 2.

I have a doubt how the pointing from each bucket need to be done when the directory size grows.

Is there a way how the pointing need to be decided.

Please help